# Quero utilizar 2 threads dentro do foreach C#

Tags: c#, thread, foreach

não tenho muita experiencia em C#. Mas estou tentando entender o código de um programa que tenho aqui.

Aqui utilizar o seguinte código:

```
foreach(var item in _main.entrada) {
....
}
```

Quero incluir o _main.saida (junto com o entrada) no foreach.... tem como fazer isso?

Comment: explique melhor... o `foreach` vai percorrer item a item de uma coleção, do que você está precisando ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quero incluir o _main.saida (junto com o entrada) no foreach.... tem como fazer isso?

Sim, basta usar o método `Union` (está no namespace System.Linq) desde que as duas coleções sejam do mesmo tipo

```
foreach (var item in _main.entrada.Union(_main.saida))
{
    ...
}
```

Exemplo completo:

```
public class MainCollection
{
    public int[] entrada;

    public int[] saida;

    public MainCollection()
    {
        entrada = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        saida = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
    }
}


public class Program
{
    private static MainCollection _main = new MainCollection();

    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var item in _main.entrada.Union(_main.saida))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

        return;
    }
}
```